# Create .env file in gh action using repo secrets

Tags: environment-variables, github-actions

So I have in github repository secret, a variable `prod_env_file` where I store my entire .env keys and values into. I am trying to generate a .env in gh actions to pull in the `prod_env_file`. Here is a example .yml code:

```
env:
  PROD_ENV_FILE: ${{ secrets.PROD_ENV_FILE }}
steps:
  - name: Configure Env
    run: |
      touch .env
      echo $PROD_ENV_FILE >> .env
```

However, my entire prod_env_file just goes in as a single liner. Accessing the `process.env.FIRST_ENV_VARIABLE` ends up containing the entire rest of prod_env_file. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the entire string has newlines removed and is concatenated into .env? Or do you mean that only the first line of the PROD_ENV_FILE secret is written into .env?

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify how your environment variables are split.

If they are divided by a space, like this:

```
SECRET1=1 SECRET2=2 SECRET3=3
```

You can simple replace the spaces with a new line using the [tr](https://linuxhint.com/bash_tr_command/) command:

```
echo "SECRET1=1 SECRET2=2 SECRET3=3" | tr " " "\n" >> .env
```

Within your Github Actions workflow would be:

```
echo $PROD_ENV_FILE | tr " " "\n" >> .env
```

And that will save the `.env` file as:

```
SECRET1=1
SECRET2=2
SECRET3=3
```